# Javascript/jQuery compare input value to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I'm relatively new to javascript and jquery. Right now I have a list of words in a txt file. I store this list in an array, and I want to compare the contents of that array to some user input. If there's a match, that specific word should be displayed.

I also use [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) to perform some typeahead functions to predict which words the user would like to search for.

In the current stage, my function finds matches on the first input character. When using more characters the function returns that no match has been found. Why is that?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="appwrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>OpenTaal Woordenboek</h3>
        <p>Voer uw zoekopdracht in:<p>
        <p><input name="searchinput" id="searchinput" data-provide="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Zoeken...">
    <p class="dict"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data;
var myArray = [];
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        txtFile.open("GET", "OpenTaal-210G-basis-gekeurd.txt", true);
        txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            data = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
            myArray = [data];
        } //"\r\n" 
    }
}
//console.write(data);

searchinput.onkeypress = function() {
//alert("The function is working!");
var formInput = document.getElementById("searchinput").value;

   if (myArray == formInput) {
   alert("There's a match!");
   $('.dict').append('<div class="result">' + myArray + '</div>')
   } else {
      alert("No match has been found..");
   }
 };
```

Comment: You're intentionally comparing the entire `myArray` to a single `formInput` value?

Comment: I think I have to iterate over the myArray to search for a match. But I don't quite know how to do this in javascript

Comment: just a tip... if you use jquery you're better of replacing your XMLHttpRequest with jquery code (ie $.ajax)

Comment: Thx for the tip kasper. Will have a look at that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use jquery, just native javascript.

After your script reading file, just do:

```
$(searchinput).on("keypress", function() {
   if ($.inArray(formInput,myArray) > -1) {
      alert("There's a match!");
   }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(searchinput).on("blur", function() {
   if ($.inArray(formInput,myArray) > -1) {
      alert("There's a match!");
   }
});
```

Comment: I do have a problem now that it's adding matches to my paragraph for every character I type. Do you know how I can avoid that?

Comment: That is the purpose of it. I have to make any matches visible :)

Comment: Maybe you don't need keypress, just use "blur" event which is reached when the focus of "input" is lost.

Comment: `$.inArray` returns 0 if the first array element matches, which evaluates as `false`. It returns -1 if there are no matches. You need to test `if ($.inArray(formInput,myArray)>=0)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to search the entire array, not just compare it to the value:

```
if ($.inArray(formInput,myArray)>=0) { // returns -1 if no match
   alert("There's a match!");
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and match the input value with array elements like :

```
   for(var i in myArray) {
       var arrayElement = myArray[i];
       if (arrayElement == formInput) {
            //Do your stuff
       }
   }
```