# Compare input to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have a list that I want to compare to a input value and when the input value doesn't match anything in my list I want to make an alert(Album don't exist).**

Here my search bar:-

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Album name">
     <button onclick="sendToPage()">Search</button>`
```

And here my list:-

```
var validSearch = ["The Stage", "Hail to the King", "Nightmare", "Avenged Sevenfold", "City of Evil", "Waking the Fallen", "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];
```

I have read [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965260/javascript-jquery-compare-input-value-to-array) but can´t get my head around it.. :)

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery compare input value to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965260/javascript-jquery-compare-input-value-to-array)

Comment: `validSearch.includes( input.value )`

Comment: validSearch.indexOf(document.getElementById("search")) > -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf on arrays. It returns the index of the element matched.
Only thing I'd suggest is you turn the search array lower or upper case first, so matching doesn't rely on the person typing it EXACTLY as you have defined it with every capital letter exactly as you wrote it.

```js
function match(elem) {
    const validSearch = [
                    "The Stage", 
                    "Hail to the King", 
                    "Nightmare", 
                    "Avenged Sevenfold", 
                    "City of Evil", 
                    "Waking the Fallen", 
                    "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];
      
    /** make search case insentive **/
    let searchKeys = validSearch.map( e => e.toLowerCase() );
    /** search the input **/
    let index = searchKeys.indexOf(elem.value.toLowerCase());
        
    /** if not matched **/
    if(index == -1) {
       window.alert("Album does not exist. Please try again");
    }
    else {
        let album = validSearch[index];
        window.alert("FOUND IT! " + album);
    }
}
+function() {
    let search = document.getElementById('search');
    document.getElementById('searchbutton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {match(search)});
}();
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Album name">
<button id="searchbutton">Search</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you explain these code blocks a little more? Do not understand why you created an empty list and then was the letter c comes from. And why you have a parameter named elem?  /** make search case insentive **/
      var searchKeys = [];
       for(c=0;c<validSearch.length;c++) {
           searchKeys[c] = validSearch[c].toLowerCase();
       }
       /** search the input **/
       var index = searchKeys.indexOf(elem.value.toLowerCase());

Comment: For the loop: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp Also, the empty list is so it can store the "case insensitive variant" of the entries. We need it initialise it first before we can fill it. Otherwise javascript doesn't know it's an array.

Comment: Just a warn: `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not a part of legacy IE js.

Comment: `.map` instead of loop variant: `validSearch.map(a=>a.toLowerCase()).indexOf(elem.value.toLowerCase())`

Comment: @vp_arth I'm of the opinion that legacy IE should die a horrible shunned death. And I personally think that someone who doesn't know a for loop shouldn't fiddle with a map function, but good for prosperity to be included in the answer ;-) but I tried to tailor my answer to the level of comprehension of the asker.

Comment: Also, your for loop is enough to find an item without `indexOf` call.

Comment: true, I was on the way to making a more complex managable checking thing, when i realised the level of the question asker, so I abandoned it, without reverting all the changes ;-)

Comment: @Tschallacka, a long time has passed, I am aware of that; however, if you were to answer the same question today, would you change anything in the code? The second question – is there a way to make that function work without relying on the "onclick" event in HTML? Perhaps, moving it entirely to js?
Thanks

Comment: @KrzysztofDelestowicz add an id to the button, the `document.getElementById('your_button_id_here').on('click', (e) => { match(document.getElementById('search'));});` and I would change the for loop into a map.`var searchKeys = validSearch.map( e => e.toLowerCase() );`

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Your array of valid searches to compare against
var validSearch = ["The Stage", "Hail to the King", "Nightmare", "Avenged Sevenfold", "City of Evil", "Waking the Fallen", "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];

//The click handler function
var sendToPage = function(e){
  //Get the input value by finding the element by its ID
  var album = document.getElementById('search').value;
  
  //Check if the value is in the array
  if(validSearch.indexOf(album) < 0){
    alert("Album don't exist");
  }else{
    alert("Album exists");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Album name">
<button onclick="sendToPage()">Search</button>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using regex instead: can search for `case insensitive` keywords and can find the closest item with limited keywords (in case user dont know how to spell correctly );

```js
var validSearch = ["The Stage", "Hail to the King", "Nightmare", "Avenged Sevenfold", "City of Evil", "Waking the Fallen", "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];

function sendToPage() {
  //get value and trim for unnecesary spaces, and set variable
  var q = document.getElementById("search").value.trim(),
    re, result;

  //return if textbox is empty
  if (!q.length > 0) {
    return;
  }

  //set RegExp (indexOf is faster but Case Sensitive)
  re = new RegExp(".*" + q.replace(/\s/g, "\\s") + ".*", "ig");

  //start searching
  validSearch.some(function(v) {
    result = re.exec(v);
    if (result) {
      return true;
    }
  })

  //if match 
  if (result !== null) {
    alert("Found it!! - " + result[0]);
  } else {
    alert("Book not Found!! - " + q);
  }

  //refresh input box
  document.getElementById("search").value = "";

}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Album name">
<button onclick="sendToPage()">Search</button>
```